# Why do they use here the prefix jQuery before the function name?

Tags: jquery

I am strugeling with this piece of code below. Why do they use the prefix jQuery before the function scrollDepth() ? What happends when I remove the prefix?

```
<script src="jquery.scrolldepth.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery.scrollDepth();
});
</script>
```

Comment: *What happens when I remove the prefix?* What happened when you did?

Comment: @PraveenKumar jQuery is a javascript library. It is not a function.

Comment: @ElGavilan: It's both.  It's also the name of the variable holding a reference to the library's main object.  It's kind of an overloaded word, now that I think about it.

Comment: Someone found the question useful!! :P One upvote.. :D :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scrollDepth is a function on the jQuery object, so it must be called on the jQuery object. (The function is from [this plugin](http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/) that adds the function to the `jQuery` object; it's not a part of jQuery itself.)

Comment: May be it has to be a comment?

Comment: looks like we've a troller in our midst

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but elaborating on what a "jQuery function" and the "jQuery object" are would make this answer less equivocal.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is trolling? Am I expected to explain what the $ and jquery objects are, and how they have functions attached to them?

Comment: @Phil, I think jbutler was referring to the downvoter, not to you :)

Comment: so it is needed to use this prefix before the function name?

Answer (score 3):

You may be familiar with the `$` symbol in *jQuery*. This is actually an *alias* for `jQuery` the object. So, we basically have an object whos name is `jQuery` and it contains all the api methods we use in jQuery

```
jQuery.each = function(){...}
jQuery.ajax = function(){...}
jQuery.makeArray = function(){...}
```

and so on

Now, *scrolldepth* is a plugin which extends the *jQuery* api similar to the approach above

```
jQuery.scrollDepth = function(){...}
```

and that is why it is called like `jQuery.scrollDepth()`

Comment: @PraveenKumar, thanks! But honestly, im explaining it more to myself than anybody else. They say teaching is the best way of learning :)

Comment: No, no, that's completely wrong. If `scrollDepth()` was a member of jQuery's prototype (`jQuery.fn`), then it would have to be called on a jQuery object (e.g. `jQuery("something").scrollDepth()`), not directly on `jQuery` itself.

Comment: Right! Accepted! `:D`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, you are right and thanks for pointing out my mistake. How would it have to be defined so that it is called like `jQuery.scrollDepth()`?

Comment: @AmmarCSE, simply with `jQuery.scrollDepth = function() {};`. Or through `jQuery.extend({ scrollDepth: function() {} })`. There are several ways to do it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, is my updated answer following the correct approach now?

Comment: @Ammar, yes, except for `filter()`, which is actually part of `jQuery.fn`. That's because you always filter *a* jQuery object (a set of matched elements), not *the* "global" jQuery object itself. Therefore, you cannot write `$.filter("something")`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, like I said, i'm teaching myself more than anything else. Thank you so much for clearing this up for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
jQuery.scrollDepth();
```

The `jQuery` "prefix" as you call it is the name of the object which has the `scrollDepth` function.  Without a reference to that object, the engine wouldn't know where to find that function.

Not all functions are global (thankfully).  In an object-oriented world, functions exist on specific objects.  You need to reference the object to invoke its functions.

Comment: ***Question:** Is jQuery OO?*

Comment: @PraveenKumar: OO is a big tent. JavaScript is OO (to the core), and jQuery uses JavaScript's OO features, so in that sense, jQuery is OO.

Comment: Ah, @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the clarification! So jQuery is OO! `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: "OO" is a very broad category that includes lots of different object-orientation practices and patterns. ("Big tent" literally would be a large enclosure that a lot of people can fit in. It's an English idiom.)

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Jquery is javascript (or a library, written in javascript). Since javascript uses OO concepts, and, by extention, jquery is OO.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I never took it as English-specific. That's got my interested peaked. Will have to find the origin of it :P

Comment: @jbutler483: I'm sure other languages use similar idioms, though possibly not quite in the same way. Idioms are funny.